# apache-nifi: how to avoid duplicate when using templates

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using NiFi to execute some queries on the remote Hive.
Since query are complex and does not SELECT anything I need to use the `PutHiveQL` processor which requires the query as FlowFile.
TO produce a Query into a flowfile I'm using a `GenerateFlowFile` followed by a `ReplaceText`.
The cluster has 3 host and the query is executed 3 times. 
Is there a way to have this query generated/executed once in a simple way?

To avoid duplicate I'm trying to use the `HashContent` followed by the `DetectDuplicate` and I'm facing the cache persistence problem. 
How can I delete an entry from the `DistributedMapCacheService` using a processor?
Is there a way to set the TTL of each entry which is stored into `DistributedMapCacheService`?

Answer (score 3):

You can schedule the GenerateFlowFile processor to run on "primary-node only" from the scheduling tab of the processor. This will cause only the primary node in your cluster to execute that processor, and thus get only one query executed.

Comment: Ok, now how can I use the crontab schedule strategy ?

Comment: yes, it does work but in this case I'm loosing the cron scheduling strategy. Is here a way to have it back ?  ?